# Object stands uninitialized in Kotlin despite initialization

Tags: android, kotlin

I am initializing my `RecyclerView` object in my `MainActivity.kt`'s `onCrete()` method but somehow it doesn't go through. I am using the `apply` function to initialize my `RecyclerView` object and attach its necessary attributes:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ...

        adapter = EntryAdapter()
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        recyclerView.apply{
            findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.userpass_recyclerview)
            layoutManager = layoutManager
            adapter = adapter
        }

        ...
    }
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Process: com.example.cryptpass_kt, PID: 29095
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cryptpass_kt/com.example.cryptpass_kt.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property recyclerView has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2853)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2928)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1609)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6703)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property recyclerView has not been initialized
        at com.example.cryptpass_kt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:46)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2806
```

Comment: Aren't you accessing the property _to initialize it_? I can't see the line numbers but that looks like what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `apply` (as any other) method needs already initialized object. But you are trying to initialize it inside `apply`'s lambda.

So you need to call `findViewById` first:

```
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.userpass_recyclerview)
recyclerView.apply {...}
```

Or, to get less code:

```
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.userpass_recyclerview).apply {
    ...
}
```

And don't forget, that you should call `findViewById` for any view only after `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing `recyclerView` here. You are using `apply` extension on `lateinit` object which is not yet initialized.

Try this,

```
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.userpass_recyclerview)
recyclerView.apply {...}
```

Just be sure, you are not doing `findViewById` too soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
class NestedRecyclerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var recyclerOuter: RecyclerView? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nested_recycler)

    recyclerOuter = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

    recyclerOuter!!.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
        this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false
    )
    val adapter = OuterAdapter(this)
    recyclerOuter!!.adapter = adapter
}
```

}

Comment: And never get inside `apply` method. Or get `NullPointerException` - depends on code.